# How to open file QuickLookPreview

Tags: url, swiftui, appstore-sandbox, quicklook, nsopenpanel

I have code below to show file (PDF) preview via `.quickLookPreview` modifier

```
Button("Preview...") {
  previewURL = documentURL!
}
.disabled(documentURL == nil)
.quickLookPreview($previewURL)
```

It works when `documentURL` variable is assigned via `NSOpenPanel` but fails when I assign it from URL obtained from data storage.

Xcode complains:

> Could not create FPSandboxingURLWrapper with url: file:///Users/...

How to allow opening file preview also for URLs obtained from storage?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by « obtained from storage ». This error means that you do not have sandbox access to the file you are trying to preview.

Comment: I was not obviously clear enough. If I select the file in NSOpenPanel, obtain its URL than I can show file preview without any issue. If I store file's URL to storage (SwiftData in this) case I can show preview even using the same URL. It's sandboxing issue so I'm wondering how to allow my app access to user's folder directly. Any particular key in info.plist file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you save a URL to which you get access via a sandbox extension granted by the open panel, you need to save bookmark data to disk, which includes the sandbox extension (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1417795-bookmarkdata?cmdf=nsurl%20bookmarkdata) instead of saving the URL itself, which is just a glorified path without any access rules associated.